# how to fix `command not found` in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to create a bash function to load certain environment variables when called, but I'm getting the error `loadenv:4: = not found`. this function, along with the variables `DEV_ENVIRONMENT_NAME, DEV_ENVIRONMENT_DIRECTORY, PROD_ENVIRONMENT_NAME and PROD_ENVIRONMENT_DIRECTORY` are defined within my `.zshrc` file so the exported variables are available in the bash session I run the function in. But I don't know what it means by the error I mentioned.

```
function loadenv() {
  environment=$1
  envname=""
  envdir=""
  if [ "$environment" == "dev" ]
  then
    echo "Assuming development credentials"
    envname="$DEV_ENVIRONMENT_NAME"
    envdir="$DEV_ENVIRONMENT_DIRECTORY"
  elif [ "$environment" == "prod" ]
  then
    echo "Assuming production credentials"
    envname="$PROD_ENVIRONMENT_NAME"
    envdir="$PROD_ENVIRONMENT_DIRECTORY"
  fi
  if [[ -z $envname || -z $envdir ]]
  then
    echo "Credentials for $environment not properly configured"
    return 1
  else
    export APP_ENVIRONMENT="$envname"
    export APP_DIRECTORY="$envdir"
    return 0
  fi

  echo "Environment '$environment' not valid"
  return 1
}
```

Comment: You mention `.zshrc`. So are you running this script with `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: You're using some bash-specific syntax, which might not work in `zsh`. Such as the `function` command to define a function, and `==` instead of `=` in `[`.

Comment: That rather cryptic error is what zsh says when you try to use `==` as an operator in a `[ ]` test expression. `=` is the correct comparison operator in that context (although bash tolerates `==` as a nonstandard synonym).

Comment: The last `echo` will never be reached, as both branches of the last `if` statement have `return` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that the **two forms** of bash logical expressions are either (**single brackets with single "="**),

```
if [ "$environment" = "dev" ]
```

or (**double brackets with "=="** ),

```
if [[ "$environment" == "dev" ]]
```

If that script is meant to be **[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)**, then you need to have

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line in your script, for it to work, regardless of the environment.

Also, be sure to **NOT source** that script into your zsh. Otherwise, it will not execute as bash.

Comment: It looks like this is intended to define functions (& maybe variables) in the calling shell, which means it *must* be run with `source` (and any shebang line will be ignored).

Comment: `[` is **not** a form of logical expression. It's just an "alias" to `test` command, although bash may also have its built-in `[` command

Comment: I will concede the semantic point of precision, but the functional result of that "command segment" is as I have pointed out, incorrect per two syntax forms allowed by bash.

Comment: The `bash` built-in `[` does, in fact, support `==` in addition to `=`. The same built-in in `zsh` does not.

Comment: I had to veify that for myself.  I stand corrected.

Comment: you're right, it was the single/double square brackets thing. Tyvm